# Let $(F,+,\cdot)$ is the finite field with $9$ elements. Then which of the following are true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, group-isomorphism

Let $(F,+,\cdot)$ is the finite field with $9$ elements. Let $G=(F,+)$ and $H=(F-\{0\}, \cdot)$ denote the underlying additive and multiplicative groups respectively. Then,

1. $G\cong (\mathbb{Z/3Z})\times(\mathbb{Z/3Z})$
2. $G\cong\mathbb{Z/9Z}$
3. $H\cong(\mathbb{Z/2Z})\times(\mathbb{Z/2Z})\times(\mathbb{Z/2Z})$
4. $G\cong (\mathbb{Z/3Z})\times(\mathbb{Z/3Z})$ and $H\cong\mathbb{Z/8Z}$

I guess $1$ and $2$ and $4$ are true but not convincingly. Can anybody help me out? Hints will be fine.

Comment: $(\mathbb{Z/3Z})\times(\mathbb{Z/3Z})$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z/9Z}$, so 1 and 2 cannot both be true!

Comment: NO.2 has a member from order 9 but its not filed you can make filed with this matrix  $$B = \begin {bmatrix} {0} & {1}\\ {1} & {2} \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G$ can be seen as a vector space over its subfield $\{0,1,2\}$, of dimension 2; this is the usual argument that a field has a prime power as its cardinality.
This shows 1) holds. This rules out 2), as $\mathbb{Z} / 9\mathbb{Z}$ has an additive element of order 9, while the first one has not.

For any field $F$, $F \setminus \{0\}$ is cyclic (as a multiplicative group) (theorem), which rules out 3. Check that 4 is indeed true.

Comment: Both parts of (4) follow, too, from facts you've given: Since $G$ is a vector space of dimension $2$ over $\Bbb Z / (3 \Bbb Z)$, $F$ is isomorphic as a group to $\Bbb Z /(3 \Bbb Z)$. Likewise, $F \setminus \{0\}$ is cyclic (and has order $9 - 1 = 8$).

Comment: What theorem are you referring in your last line?

Comment: The theorem that the multiplicative group of a finite field is always cyclic. This is a standard fact in algebra courses on finite fields.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that earlier. Thakns

Answer (score 2):

Note that the characteristic of the field is 3.So the field F is the splitting field of  $x^{3^2}-x$ on $F_3$. I doubt whether (1) holds. Since (0,1) does not have a reverse.
Update: Since G is an ADDITIVE group I think (1) holds.

Comment: How this helps?

Comment: You can simply calculate all the roots of $x^{3^2}-x$ in  complex  field. And a finite field is unique. So it may help you understand the structure of the field.

Comment: Hmmmm understood.

Answer (score 2):

For (3) and (4) if you want a elementary reasoning, you can do this:

In $H$ any element has order $1,2,4$ or $8$. If you assume by contradiction that there is no element of order $8$, then all $8$ elements of $H$ satisfy 
$$x^4=1$$
Therefore this polynomial has 8 roots, contradiction.

This shows that $H$ has an element of order $8$ and is thus cyclic.

**P.S.** This is the basic idea behind the proof of the Theorem quoted in the other answer.

**For (1) or (2)** We show that every element $x \neq 0$ in $G$ must have order $3$:

In $F$ you have
$$(x+x+x) \cdot (x+x+x) = 9x^2 =0$$
with the last equality following from the fact that $G$ has order $9$.

Since $F$ is a field you get $$x+x+x=0$$

Now, since $G$ is an abelian group with $9$ elements, it is easy to prove that the above relation implies $G \sim (\mathbb{Z/3Z})\times(\mathbb{Z/3Z})$, as there are only 2 abelian groups with 9 elements.

If you want a Group Theoretical proof, pick $x \neq 0$ in $G$ and $y \in G \backslash \{ 0, x, 2x \}$. It is very easy to show that 
$$G \sim < x> \times <y> $$

Comment: That's smooth. Any elementary reasoning for 1 and 2 ?

Comment: @KprimeX Added.

Comment: @Mr.Rock YES but with different multiplication.

Comment: Can you give an example of such field (a field K of nine elements where K$^x$ is cyclic) ? @N.S.

Comment: Could it be $F_9=\{ 0,1,2,x,x+1,x+2,2x,2x+1,2x+2\}$ ?

Comment: @LeylaAlkan And what is the multiplication table? All you need is to pick some irreducible quadratic polynomial $P(x)$ over $\mathbb F_3$ and take the factor $\mathbb F_3[X]/<P(x)>$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $B$ is a matrix on $F_3$
 $$B = \begin {bmatrix} {0} & {1}\\ {1} & {2} \end{bmatrix}
$$   $$F_9 = \{ {0}, {I} , {B} ,{B^{2}} ,{B^{3}} ,{B^{4}} ,{B^{5}} ,{B^{6}} ,{B^{7}}  \} $$

then $NO.4$ is correct. because two finite fields with the same number of elements are isomorphic .